# PBS directive with variable resource request

Tags: shell, cluster-computing

I use a shell script to launch several jobs on a computing cluster by calling `qsub` inside a loop. I use the loop to give each job a different starting value. I wanted to specify the number of cores for each job to request by simply passing a number to the shell script when I run it from the command line. For example

```
./lauchJobs.sh 8
```

would launch jobs which requests 8 cores per node. I attempted to do this with

```
#!/bin/tcsh
#check that all input arguments are there
if ($# != 3) then
    echo "This script requires three input arguments: (i) number of cores per job, (ii) starting guessNum, (iii) ending guessNum"
else
    foreach iNum (`seq $2 1 $3`) #loop over guess numbers
        qsub  -v iGuess=${iNum} estimate.pbs
    end
endif
```

(yes, technically my first example should have been something like `./launchJobs.sh 8 1 50` because I expect three arguments)

And estimate.pbs began with

```
#!/bin/tcsh 
#PBS -l pmem=1gb,nodes=1:ppn=${nCores},walltime=60:00:00
```

The problem is that `${nCores}` did not resolve to the value I passed from the shell script because it is inside the PBS directive.

Is it possible to write a script file and PBS file that will allow me to specify the number of cores to request by passing it to the script, as in `./lauchJobs.sh 8` ?

Comment: `HERE` documents may be able to help you. (search for `[tcsh] HERE` (or if no results there change to `EOF` or `EOS` (many others are possible, but those are very common). Not clear to me why you have `#!/bin/tcsh` at the top of the PBS directive file, but I dont even know what PBS is. Going to bed now, so can't spend time on this now. Maybe tomorrow, but I expect to be busy. Good luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to specify `nodes=1:ppn=${nCores}` in estimate.pbs.

You can also invoke qsub in this way:

```
qsub -l nodes=1:ppn=${1} -v iGuess=${iNum} estimate.pbs
```